Forwarding node stream data
I have a react UI which is being served from node server. So all the API calls made from UI will go through the node server and then the Back-end API's.
Using fetch.
I am trying to make a file download request from UI , which will hit the UI node server and from there the actual API will be triggered.
I am streaming the excel file as response from backend to the node UI server (res.arrayBuffer) . How to rightly forward the response from node UI server to the UI? So I will be able to download the file ?
I have tried forwarding the received stream(res.arrayBuffer) and also tried forwarding it as  res.text() and convert the data in UI from text to arrayBuffer
but the downloaded file is always corrupt and very less in size pile 2-5bytes
Can anyone help on this?

Please, show code instead of describing it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
